# ID of a current process leads to an error while ID of any previous process works fine

Tags: rest, express, routes, httpresponse

When a user clicks on `pay` button in `index.html`,
form data is sent to the `/stk` route in `server.js`
where the form data alongside other parameters are
used as the body of an api request which initiates
an `STK push` on the user's phone at the same time
a response sent back indicating that the payment has
been accepted for processing. The reponse includes
an ID called 'checkOutRequestId' which is used to make
a `transaction status query` to establish whether the
user made payment successfully or cancelled based
on response received in `/transactionStatus` route.

When the current 'checkOutRequestId' is sent as the body in a post
request to `/transactionStatus` route, I keep catching an error
logged as: `trnx attempt fail Request failed with status code 500`.

However, when I use 'checkOutRequestId' from any previous process
the kind of response expected from `/transactionStatus` route is received
without an error only that now the response is for a previous
process and not the current one.

i.e If on clicking the button the process led to the return of
such an ID: `checkOutRequestId: ws_CO_06112022153728xxxxxxxxxxx2`
, which is then used as the body sent to `/transactionStatus`
route, an error (500) is caught.

When this same ID `(ws_CO_06112022153728xxxxxxxxxxx2)` is used as
the body to `/transactionStatus` route in a new `post request`.
A response matching that ID is returned successfully.

How do I go about resolving this problem?

Note: I'm trying to work with an api called `Lipa Na MPESA
Online Transaction Query'

```
//index.html
<form id="myForm" >
        <input id="phone" type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Enter phone">
        <input id="amount" type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Enter amount" inputmode="numeric">
        <!-- <button id="submit">Make payment</button> -->
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Pay</button>
</form>

//index.js
const myForm = document.querySelector("#myForm");

let amount = document.querySelector("#amount");
amount.value = 1;
let cash = Number(amount.value);

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const phone = document.querySelector("#phone").value;

  const url = "http://localhost:port/stk";
  const body = {
    phone: phone,
    amount: cash,
  };
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset =UTF-8" },
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("in front", data.CheckoutRequestID);
      trnxStatus(data.CheckoutRequestID);
    });
});

function trnxStatus(checkoutReqId) {
  const checkoutRequestID = checkoutReqId;
  const body = {
    checkoutReqId: checkoutRequestID,
    //if ID from previous process is used here, the process works successfully
    // checkoutReqId: "ws_CO_06112022153728xxxxxxxxxxx2",
  };

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset =UTF-8" },
  };
  const trnxUrl = "http://localhost:port/transactionStatus/";
  fetch(trnxUrl, options)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("response data", data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error message", err.message);
    });
}

//server.js
const businessShortCode = process.env.SHORTCODE;
const passKey = process.env.PASSKEY;

let date = new Date();
const timestamp =
  date.getFullYear() +
  ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

const password = new Buffer.from(
  businessShortCode + passKey + timestamp
).toString("base64");

app.post("/stk", generateToken, async (req, res) => {

  const phone = `254${req.body.phone.substring(1)}`;
  const amount = req.body.amount;

  await axios
    .post(
      "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest",
      {
        BusinessShortCode: businessShortCode,
        Password: password,
        Timestamp: timestamp,
        TransactionType: "CustomerPayBillOnline", //"CustomerBuyGoodsOnline"
        Amount: amount,
        PartyA: phone,
        PartyB: businessShortCode,
        PhoneNumber: phone,
        CallBackURL: "https://011c-179-000-1312-63.ngrok.io/stk_callback",
        AccountReference: "Test",
        TransactionDesc: "Test",
      },
      {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(200).json(data.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json(err.message);
    });
});

app.post("/transactionStatus", generateToken, async (req, res) => {

  const checkoutReqId = req.body.checkoutReqId;
  const trnxUrl = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpushquery/v1/query";
  await axios
    .post(
      trnxUrl,
      {
        BusinessShortCode: businessShortCode,
        Password: password,
        Timestamp: timestamp,
        CheckoutRequestID: checkoutReqId,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((data) => {
      res.status(200).json(data.data);
      console.log("check data response", data.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("trnx attempt fail", err.message);
      res.status(400).json(err.message);
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app is running on port ${port}`);
});
```